# Can't figure out how to copy numbers from file to arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io

I've just started learning C# and got small problem with reading from file.
My file is called data.dat and it looks like this:

```
6  
1 5  
4 5  
1 4  
7 3  
3 6  
4 7
```

The first line in that file should be read into single integer and it means the number of tasks (how many pairs of number are in this file, started from the 2nd line till the end). Another lines are pair of numbers - ex. (1, 5). The first numbers in this pairs(1st column) should be added to one array - `pArray = {1, 4, 1, 7, 3, 4}`, 2nd column should be added to another array - `rArray = {5, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7}`.

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(@"pathToFile")){
    numberOfTaks = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());   }
```

I tried something like this for reading the first line, but completely don't know how to read another lines and spliting them into different arrays. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Are you required to use Arrays (homework)?  If not, I'd use List<int> instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You could do something like:

int count = int.Parse(file.ReadLine().Trim());
int[] pArray = new int[count], rArray = new int[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    string[] line = file.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    pArray[i] = int.Parse(line[0].Trim());
    rArray[i] = int.Parse(line[1].Trim());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the count given on the first line is always correct there's no need to read it.

```
// using statement
using System.Linq;

// Reads the data file into memory
var pairs = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\path\to\file\data.dat");

// Skip the first line, split each line by space, take first element, convert to int
var pArray = pairs.Skip(1).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[0]));

// Same as above, but take second element
var rArray = pairs.Skip(1).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[1]));
```

Output:

> pArray = {1, 4, 1, 7, 3, 4}
>   rArray = {5, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7}

The two arrays are actually IEnumerable, if you want a straight array pop `.ToArray()` on the end like so:

```
var pArray = pairs.Skip(1).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[0])).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

all the line (on my opinion) must pass through a string variable and you can take count of the lines.
For separate each number you can do something like this:

```
string myLine = reader.ReadLine();
string firstChar = myLine.Split(0,1); // To take the first char
```

and make it for all the lines. If you try with the debug is not so hard. 
After you have all the char in a line you can create your array.
Hope it helps you to understand.
Bye!

Answer (score 0):

this is one approach (assuming your file's format is correct)...

```
//read all lines from file
List<string>lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"pathToFile").ToList();
int number = int.Parse(lines[0]);
//list to hold first column
List<int> firstList = new List<int>();
//list to hold second
List<int> secondList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i< lines.Count; i++) // iterate through all lines, starting at second (index 1)
{
    //split line by space
    string[] numbersFromLine = lines[i].Split(' ');
    //put first part of splitted line into list
    firstList.Add(int.Parse(numbersFromLine[0]));
    //put second part of splitted line into list
    secondList.Add(int.Parse(numbersFromLine[1]));
}
```

and, if you really need arrays, you can convert to arrays from list like this:

```
var firstArray = firstList.ToArray();
var secondArray = secondList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:-

```
// Read in the complete file
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(@"pathToFile");

// Split on all Whitespace (removing all empty entries)
string[] numbers = fileContents.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Process all the numbers
int numberOfRows = int.Parse(numbers[0]);

int[] pArray = new int[numberOfRows];
int[] rArray = new int[numberOfRows];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
{
    pArray[i] = int.Parse(numbers[(i * 2) + 1]);
    rArray[i] = int.Parse(numbers[(i * 2) + 2]);
}
```

Comment: Only just noticed the similarities between my answer and the one posted by Nino. IMO Nino's answer is better in as much as it gives more opportunity to catch errors in the format of the input file.